# Give data from facebook and show it in array with JSON

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, json, nsarray

I want get image from public perfil of Facebook and show it in my iPhone. I'm using the Facebook Developer method "graph.facebook.com" and later i want read it with JSON, but when i save data in NSArray, it SIGABRT.

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

NSData *datosAlbum = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

NSError *error=nil;

NSString *datosString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:datosAlbum encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[datosAlbum release];

SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];

NSLog(@"%@",[parser objectWithString: datosString error: &error]);
NSArray *datos_array= [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[parser objectWithString: datosString error: &error]];
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks for all and Merry Christmas!

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try: https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture
and for the json https://graph.facebook.com/4